# Android : Handling of ImageRequest Null Pointer Google Volley

Tags: android

just want to know if, how will i set default image in imageView if I'm requesting into non-existing image URL.

This is my code, hope someone will help me. Thanks in advance.

```
Bitmap bitmap = imageCache.get(cards.getCardID());
    final ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardImage);
    if(bitmap!=null){       
        image.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, 200));
    } else {
        if(cards.getCardListImage()!=null){
            imageUrl = cards.getCardListImage();
        } else {
            imageUrl = BeaconAppConstants.IMAGE_IF_ABSENT;
        }
        ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(imageUrl, 
                new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Bitmap arg0) {
                image.setImageBitmap(arg0);
                imageCache.put(cards.getCardID(), arg0);
            }
        }, 
        65, 
        65, 
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, 
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
                Log.d("Error occured", arg0.getMessage());
                // set image on this line
            }
        });
        queue.add(request);
    }
```

This is my logcat output :

```
1-15 23:23:59.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-15     23:23:59.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18331): Process: com.android.bts.beaconapp, PID: 18331 11-15 23:23:59.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18331): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message 11-15 23:23:59.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18331): at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method) 11-15 23:23:59.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18331): at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:232) 11-15 23:23:59.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18331): at com.android.bts.beaconapp.adapter.BeaconCardAdapter$2.onErrorResponse(BeaconCard‌​Adapter.java:94)
```

Comment: the app closes if the variable "imageUrl" contains non-existing image url

Comment: Can you upload errorlog?

Comment: Log.d("Error occured", arg0.getMessage()); you can't do that. arg0 or getMessage() can be null.

Comment: 11-15 23:23:59.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 23:23:59.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18331): Process: com.android.bts.beaconapp, PID: 18331
11-15 23:23:59.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18331): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
11-15 23:23:59.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18331):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
11-15 23:23:59.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18331):  at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:232)
11-15 23:23:59.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18331):  at com.android.bts.beaconapp.adapter.BeaconCardAdapter$2.onErrorResponse(BeaconCardAdapter.java:94)

Comment: wow, thanks for pointing not to use "Log.d("Error occured", arg0.getMessage());", got already the answer. thanks a lot man! :)